Movie about a woman witnessing a serial killer in the woods and falling in love
The movie I'm looking for is about a serial killer that kills in the woods and a romance with woman falling in love. It's not a slasher nor a horror movie really.
A young woman witnesses one of his killings in the woods on a river and begins to follow him, falling in love. 
But the killer doesn't have feelings but even then she follows him and tries to change him.
In the end, they're both on a boat on a lake, and one of them who can't swim dies drowned (it's not a killing actually). I think it's the girl who tried to awaken some feelings in him by jumping in the water and forcing him to save her.

Sounds like Tenderness

Three lives. Buffalo detective Lt. Cristofuoro, whose catatonic wife is in hospital, takes a special interest in Eric Komenko, a juvenile who killed his parents and will be freed on his 18th birthday. So has Lori Cranston, 15 or 16, her body fully developed and the object of lust by her boss and her mother's new boyfriend. She keeps a scrapbook about Eric, and when he's released from custody, she hides in the backseat of his car, insisting he take her with him on a trip toward Albany where he's planning to meet a girl. Cristofuoro is certain Eric will kill again, so he follows. It's clear early on that Cristofuoro's probably right, but what's Lori's motivation?




You can see the end/drowning scene in the end of this video



